# Finder question: missing expansion triangle in list view

Tags: macos, finder

I have a list of folders shown in list view mode in Finder. But for some weird reason the regular click to expand triangle button which is present on each folder icon has disappeared. This issue is only sticky in one of the many folders in the system.

Do you know how I can re-enable it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The window may be using one of the "Arrange By" options. Disclosure triangles are not available in "arranged" views. If that's the case, you can choose `View → Arrange By → None` or press <kbd>^ control</kbd><kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

On Mojave the concept is called "Group" instead of "Arrange". Keyboard shortcut is the same. Menu item is found as follows: `View → Use Groups`.

Comment: Yes! this solution work. As it turned out I must have put the folder in Arrange mode unconsciously. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks for this, thought it was related to a recent OS Update (which it might have been).

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this. Worked fine for me .

View > Arrange By > None

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried restarting the computer or logging out and back in?

Try to restart the Finder using

```
killall Finder
```

in the Terminal. This application is located at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`.