# Finder folders have no triangle to twirl

Tags: macos, finder

I am running 10.9.5 and some folders in list view have no triangles by the subfolders. I would love to know why this happening and how to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set the folder to be "Arranged By..." something e.g. name.  Go to the View menu; choose "Arrange By", then "None".  You can still sort the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Arrange By option is set to None.

[Finder question: missing expansion triangle in list view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40115/finder-question-missing-expansion-triangle-in-list-view)