# Remove expansion triangle in list view in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I personally prefer list view **without** the expansion triangle, unlike [Finder question: missing expansion triangle in list view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40115/finder-question-missing-expansion-triangle-in-list-view)

I am able to get it to work by selecting an "arrange by" option, but it does not apply to all folders. How can I apply this as the default? Is there a terminal command or something for it?

Answer (score 1):

Set up the Finder window with your desired settings, then press ⌘J and click Use as Defaults.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I didn't see it on the bottom of "show view options"! However, the settings changes randomly as I navigate to other folders, which I guess they were overriding the default? Is there a way to force finder to always use the default?